# What are the lyrics of goddess Durga's dhyan mantra?

Tags: durga, devi-bhagavata-purana, markandeya-purana

Can anybody please provide me the full lyrics of durga dhyan mantra (jatajoota samayukta) with meaning. It will be better, if the main shlokas can be provided in Devanagari.

Comment: You can get them on YouTube or Google. I got a result in Google. For transliteration, use some online transliteration tool.   Our site recommends transliteration into English because Devanagari is not understood by all.

Comment: I mean shlokas in Sanskrit but the meanings should be in English. I'm not getting lyrics in Devanagari script. I have searched many times. So I have came here. @Sarvabhouma

Comment: If you have found lyrics in English, you can just transliterate them using online transliteration tools. Answers would be only copy paste of some site which are discouraged.

Answer (score 0):

Durga Dhyan Mantra दुर्गाध्यानम्
दुर्गाध्यानम्

Durga Dhyan Mantra

जटाजूटसमायुक्तामर्धेन्दुकृरलक्षणाम् ।
लोचनात्रयसंयुक्तां पद्नेन्दुसदृशाननाम् ॥१॥

आतसीपुष्पवर्णाभां सुप्रतिष्ठां सुलोचनाम् ।
नवयौवनसम्पन्नां सर्वाभरणभूषिताम् ॥२॥

उग्रचण्डा प्रचण्डा च चण्डोग्रा चण्डनायिका ।
चन्डा चण्डवती चैव चण्डरूपाति चण्डिका ॥

Attend to Durga, Who is associated with a hair-bun of matted locks, Who has made eighth-night moon as a forehead-mark, Who has three eyes, Who has a face resembling a moon and a lotus, Whose is radiant with light of blue colour (that of linseed flower), Who is well respected, Whose eyes are conducive, Who is full of youthful energy, and Who is decorated by all the ornaments. [1—2]

She is surrounded by eight Skaktis, namely- Ugrachandaa, Prachandaa, Chandograa, Chandanayikaa, Chandaa, Chandabati, Chandarupaa,Ati chandikaa.I pray to Her for the “Chaturbarga” (Dharma, Artha, Kama, Moksha)that is the goal for every human being.

सुचारुवदनां तद्वत्पीनोन्नतपयोधराम् ।
त्रिभङ्गस्थानसंस्थानम् महिषासुरमर्दिनीम् ॥३॥

तीक्ष्णबाणं तथा शक्ति वामतोsपि निबोधत ।
त्रिशुलं दक्षिणे दद्यात्खङ्गं चक्र क्रमादध: ॥४॥

उग्रचण्डा प्रचण्डा च चण्डोग्रा चण्डनायिका ।
चन्डा चण्डवती चैव चण्डरूपाति चण्डिका ॥

Attend to Durgā, Who has a beautiful and conducive face, Who is having enlarged breasts due to full milk, Who is the killer of Mahiṣāsura while standing at the point of rout of the three worlds, Who should be given trident in right hand, Who should hold scymitar and cakra in that order in other right hands, Who should have a sharp arrow and śakti in the left hands. [3—4]

She is surrounded by eight Skaktis, namely- Ugrachandaa, Prachandaa, Chandograa, Chandanayikaa, Chandaa, Chandabati, Chandarupaa,Ati chandikaa.I pray to Her for the “Chaturbarga” (Dharma, Artha, Kama, Moksha)that is the goal for every human being.

खेटकं पूर्णचापं च पाशमङ्कुशमूर्द्धजम् ।
घण्टां च परशुं वापि वामत: सन्निवेशयेत् ॥५॥

अधस्तान्महिषं तद्वद्विशिरस्कं प्रदर्शयेत् ।
शिरश्छेदोद्भवं तद्वद्दानवं खङ्गपाणोनम् ॥६॥

A shield, a full bow, a string, a stick, a high flag, a bell, or an axe can be rested in Her left hands. Beneath that, a buffalo with a head belonging to it should be shown. One should show the demon as emerging out from the body of beheaded buffalo, holding a scymitar in hands.[5—6]

हृदि शुलेन निर्भिन्नं निर्दयन्तं विभूषितम् ।
रक्तरक्तीकृताङ्गं च रक्तविस्फारितेक्षणम् ॥७॥

वेष्टितं नागपाशेन भृकुटीभीषणाननम् ।
सपाशवामहस्तेन धृतकेशं च दुर्गया ॥८॥

उग्रचण्डा प्रचण्डा च चण्डोग्रा चण्डनायिका ।
चन्डा चण्डवती चैव चण्डरूपाति चण्डिका ॥

One should show his heart as pierced by a spear, without mercy. One should decorate his body with blood of red color and his red eyes should be opened wide. One should show him as tied with a nāgapāśa (snake-chain), and his eyebrows should be meeting on a scary head. One should show his hairs held together by the left hand of Durgā. [7—8]

She is surrounded by eight Skaktis, namely- Ugrachandaa, Prachandaa, Chandograa, Chandanayikaa, Chandaa, Chandabati, Chandarupaa,Ati chandikaa.I pray to Her for the “Chaturbarga” (Dharma, Artha, Kama, Moksha)that is the goal for every human being.

वमद्रुधिरवक्तं च देव्या: सिंहं प्रदर्शयेत् ।
देव्यास्त दक्षिणं पादं समसिंहोपरिस्थितम् ॥९॥

उग्रचण्डा प्रचण्डा च चण्डोग्रा चण्डनायिका ।
चन्डा चण्डवती चैव चण्डरूपाति चण्डिका ॥

किञ्चिदूर्ध्वं तथा वाममङ्गुष्ठो महिषोपरि ।
स्तूयमानं च तद्रूपममरै: सन्निवेशयेत् ॥१०॥

उग्रचण्डा प्रचण्डा च चण्डोग्रा चण्डनायिका ।
चन्डा चण्डवती चैव चण्डरूपाति चण्डिका ॥

॥ इति ॥

One should show the lion of Goddess as drooling with blood on face. The right foot of Goddess should be situated in the middle above of lion. Somewhat high and somewhat left should be the left thumb (of Goddess) above the buffalo. One should have this form in eulogy by immortal demi-gods.[9—10]

She is surrounded by eight Skaktis, namely- Ugrachandaa, Prachandaa, Chandograa, Chandanayikaa, Chandaa, Chandabati, Chandarupaa,Ati chandikaa.I pray to Her for the “Chaturbarga” (Dharma, Artha, Kama, Moksha)that is the goal for every human being.